R Markdown usage question: How to display plot in R Studio plots window when using R Markdown?
I typically use R Markdown to prepare scripts that I can easily share with my colleagues. In the past, I exported high-quality plots from RStudio using the ‘Export/Save as Image…/Save as SVG’ feature, which seems to be not an option with R Markdown. One aspect I find particularly useful is the ability to dynamically adjust the plot size by dragging the RStudio window, allowing for on-the-spot decisions about the best size for the plot. Could you suggest a method for writing scripts that are not only presentable but also utilize RStudio’s graphical user interface to export plots at the desired size? Also, open to hear about better workflows.

If you are editing the .Rmd file in RStudio and execute the code in a chunk, the plot appears inline by default, but you can change that in the options.  Look for Tools | Global Options | R Markdown | Show output inline, and uncheck it.

Followed these instruction and plots still appear in line not as expected in R studio's plot tab. Could this be linked to the fact I run it on Rstudio server?

That sounds likely.
